# Unity 8 Preview in 14.04 - Will it break anything?

Tags: unity, 14.04, unity8

I recently upgraded to 14.04, and I love it. I also want to be able to try out the Unity 8 Desktop Preview, but this is my main system and I'd rather not mess it up.

There doesn't seem to be any fancy doohickies that you have to do to install it, just running `sudo apt-get install unity8-desktop-section-mir`, as [mentioned here on OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/unity-8-desktop-preview-session-14-04). I also noticed that several Mir packages were installed during the upgrade to 14.04. Will I need to have anything installed, or does 14.04 come with the required packages?

So, I'm taking it safe and asking here. Does anyone know if installing Unity 8 will break anything in 14.04? I don't have any other DEs installed, so that shouldn't be an issue.

**Edit**:

I was doing some research and found [this page](https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity8/). It mentions building Unity8 and running it from a folder

> **Download source**
>
> create a parent folder to not pollute your setup. so that you can have
>   different unity branches there (trunk, WIP etc)

would this be safer?

Answer (score 1):

The safest option is probably to install the `unity8-desktop-session-mir`. This should pull in any other packages it may need. You can see dependencies here:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/misc/unity8-desktop-session-mir

It *shouldn't* break anything. Being an Ubuntu package it should be somewhat tested to cause no unrelated issues.

Installing from source would probably be less safe, unless you really know what you are doing. The package option allows the software system to manage the files and easily remove them when needed.